# Native script DatePicker shows wrong value of month

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular-nativescript

I have a problem in DatePicker in native-script. It starting month from 0

For example:

```
   const datePicker = <DatePicker>args.object;
   datePicker.minDate = new Date(1975, 1, 1);
```

output:it shows 
 1 Feb 1975

Comment: JavaScript Date indexes month from 0, so it should be expected.

Comment: resolved by  addition of  "month - 1"  : ```datePicker.month =month-1 ;```

Answer (score 1):

The month property starts from 0 to 11, just try to change your index 1 to 0.

For example,

```html
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var d = new Date(2018, 0, 21);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d;
</script>
```